# What are the pros and cons of greased feet in boots?

Tags: health, boots, footwear

I was just reading this answer at [Can you keep your feet warm in ski boots on a very cold day?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/3556/can-you-keep-your-feet-warm-in-ski-boots-on-a-very-cold-day/3559#3559)

> Yes, add fat to your feet. I don't mean gain weight. Just slather it on before putting socks on. Petroleum jelly will work, as will almost any other fat (other than coconut oil). A nice layer of fat, even external, does wonders for heat retention.

Ignoring the ick factor that is mentioned in some of the comments to the answer.  From a physical perspective what are the pros and cons of using Petroleum jelly or some other grease on your booted feet when out doors?  I want to know about impacts to foot health as well as impact to socks and boots.

Comment: Ick.  It's also hard to believe that a little fat would be better than adding another layer of socks, assuming the right sock material, of course.

Comment: Who is going to wash the grease out of the socks?  Don't depend on your SO to do it.

Comment: @ab2 The way to clean the socks afterwards is with a lighter.

Comment: And what's wrong with using coconut oil?

Comment: @MartinF you should ask your question as new question or as a comment under the answer I linked to in my question.

Comment: @MartinF I'd imagine that it just thins down too much from the heat of your feet and soaks into the socks. Though i'd imagine in the heat of a boot most fats would do that, then they'd knacker all the technical properties of your sock fabric.

Comment: There are very many vegetable oils that are more runny than coconut oil!

Answer (score 3):

Petroleum Jelly (Vaseline) on feet can be used to,

- [Treat dry cracked feet.](http://www.vaseline.us/skin-health-care/dry-feet-essential-tips-for-treating-dry-skin-on-feet.html)
- [Treat cracked heals.](http://www.vaseline.us/skin-health-care/how-to-help-heal-dry-cracked-heels.html)
- [Reduce friction and therefore the chances of getting blisters.](https://www.aad.org/public/skin-hair-nails/injured-skin/blisters)

From personal experience the downsides are the ick factor and you are going to ruin your socks. It would be hard to get it out of shoes or boots afterwards.

There are also people who don't like the idea of putting a [petroleum product on their skin](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/10/21/vaseline-petroleum-jelly_n_4136226.html).